# Limit on number of available messages on SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Based on the documentation ([AWS SQS Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/limits-queues.html)) the maximum number of inflight messages per queue (in a standard queue) is 120,000.
But does SQS have any limit for available messages in a queue?
I'd guess that there is no limit on the number of messages that a queue can hold in SQS, but I haven't found any explicit statement on the documentation about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unlimited, per the [SQS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> A single Amazon SQS message queue can contain an unlimited number of
>   messages. However, there is a 120,000 limit for the number of inflight
>   messages for a standard queue and 20,000 for a FIFO queue. Messages
>   are inflight after they have been received from the queue by a
>   consuming component, but have not yet been deleted from the queue.

Comment: if sqs worker/consumer gets the message and change the visibilitytimeout then message will still be considered as inflight message.

Comment: @gouravkumar yes, but I'm not sure why you mention that. It doesn't conflict with the quoted statement from the SQS FAQ.